# GPG suite decrypted file is 0 byte

Tags: gnupg

I have a file encrypted with GPG suite 2 years ago...

I need it now and tried to decrypt it but the resulting zip file is 0 bytes :((

What does that mean ?

I also tried the CLI and Im getting

```
gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key
```

EDIT

If I put --batch the file is decrypted but I cannot find it anywhere

`gpg --passphrase "mypassword" -d --batch --ignore-mdc-error myFilePath`

`gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected`

Comment: Questions: (1) What is your operating system? (2) Is gpg the latest version? (3) Or is gpg the same version as encrypted the file? There have been reports about gpg version 2 having problems decrypting gpg version 1.4.

Comment: OSX 10.14.1, latest GPG using homebrew, not sure what was my version of the encrypted file; I was using GPG tools at the time 2 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your current homebrew version by [GPG 1.4](https://gnupg.org/download/).

One alarming text from the above link:

> GnuPG 1.4 is the old, single binary version *which still support the unsafe PGP-2 keys*.

As the last version 1.4 dates from only 5 months ago, this might explain why
your current version doesn't support your keys format, if they are in the
PGP-2 format.

(General note: When files are encrypted, one should always take in account
the possibility that software changes might make decryption impossible
after some years. Encryption is not a long-term solution.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I'll try I went to the link but this is not a binary... I am not familiar how to compile.. :s is it possible to install with brew ?

Comment: actually I managed to install it and tried to decrypt but no success with the same command as above. gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.23

Comment: actually it worked but different command using `gpg --decrypt file > file.zip`

Comment: could I please ask a last advice, now I managed to decrypt; I would like to uninstall the 1,4; how can I do that with files I had to compile myself, brew is saying that v2.21 is already installed so I have a conflict I guess, if I do `gpg --version` I get 1.4

Comment: actually I got it `brew link --overwrite gnupg`